Explanation of quantum algorithm for numerical gradient estimation
My question concerns this algorithm: Fast Quantum Algorithm for Numerical Gradient Estimation by Stephen P Jordan https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0405146
I am unable to understand this step of the algorithm (bottom right corner of page 1, some of the explanation continues onto page 2).

It seems a lot of steps are skipped so I was hoping someone more familiar with the algorithm could reconstruct it.
The function $f$ is being evaluated in the range $[-l/2 , l/2]$, as is implied earlier in the text. I can understand the input to $f$ in the expression. $f \left( l \left( \delta/N - \frac{\vec{1}}{2} \right) \right)$
$\delta$ is in the fixed point integer encoding. We divide $\delta$ by N to normalise the values to the range $[0,1]$, then we subtract $\frac{\vec{1}}{2}$ to shift this to $[-1/2, 1/2]$. Finally multiplying by $l$ gets it to the right range for input.
The $N$ mutiplied outside the function application also swaps between real number and fixed point encoding, this time the division is by $m$, assuming the range of $f$ is $[-m/2, m/2]$.
I am not sure why there is a division by $l$. There is also a factor $N_0$ that I don't understand which is not written as it cancels with the $/N_0$ from the root of unity in the Fourier state.
